# Educated guess for algebraic approximation

Tags: rational-points, approximation-algorithms, rational-functions, rootfinding

I found a very neat [ancient hindi formula](https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/india-sqrt-encyc.pdf) for approximating square roots using rational numbers. After doing some algebra on the formula, i came across with this recursive relation:

Given any number $k\in\ \mathbb{Q}$:
$$\sqrt{k}≈x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^4+6kx_n^2+k^2}{4(x_n^3+kx_n)}$$
In the original article, it is stated that successive iterations of this relation result in a cuartic convergence, so this formula is very sharp.
However, for this formula to actually work, we need to make an initial guess:
We have to pick some $x_0\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that for a sufficiently small open interval…let’s say $I=(\frac{\sqrt{|k|}}{2};\sqrt{|k|})\subset \mathbb{Q}$:
$$x_0\in I$$
This is great, because now we can have a way to **generalize root approximation** for some algebraic numbers. But the question arises: is there any way to actually “compute” $x_0$ (as in an algebraic function in terms of $k$; $a(k)$) algebraically? The best description i came off with is the floor function $x_0=\lfloor\sqrt{|k|}\rfloor$ But that would not be an actual algebraic expression for this, as i would like. Can you come up with anything better?

Comment: one may solve $x^2 - k y^2 = 1$  in (positi ve) integers, then $x/y$   is a good start

Comment: Lubin described the  simplest looking common approach to Pell at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-11/    there was also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakravala_method

Comment: @WillJagy but can you prove the solution is in the given  interval?